# Negative Log inside Negative Log

Tags: logarithm, gumbel-distribution

Is there a name for a function which is like $f(x)=-\log(-\log(x))$ where $0<x<1$?

Or, is there any name for this function $g(x)=x+\log(\frac{1}{x})$ where $0<x$?

Exchanging $x=-\log k$ in $g(x)$ gives $f(k)$ and I would like to know about those functions any deeper, but I am having trouble searching about them. I know the first equation is used for Gumbel sampling, but I want to know more general characteristics of this function. If there are any specific name or related function that I can search for, I will be very glad to know.

(I have asked same question in math stackexchange, but I thought I should ask here too since the function seems to be related to imformation theory or distributions etc.)

Comment: That resembles the complimentary log-log, which is $\log(-\log(1-\pi))$, which is the inverse of the extreme value distribution CDF. It's not exactly what you've specified but it might be close enough to get you started?

Comment: It is the inverse of the Erdős-Rényi approximation $e^{-e^{-x}}$ related to the coupon-collector's distribution